# Submodular function composition with set function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The composition of a submodular function $f : 2^Y \to \mathbb{R}$ with a function $g : 2^X \to 2^Y$ is submodular if $\lvert g(\{x\}) \rvert = 1$ for all $x \in X$ and $g(A \cup B) = g(A) \cup g(B)$. This can be seen fairly easily by substituting the composition of functions into the definition of submodularity:

- $f(g(X \cup \{x\})) - f(g(X)) \ge f(g(Y \cup \{x\})) - f(g(Y))$
- $f(g(X) \cup g(\{x\})) - f(g(X)) \ge f(g(Y) \cup g(\{x\})) - f(g(Y))$ because $g(A \cup B) = g(A) \cup g(B)$
- Define $\{y\} = g(\{x\})$ because $\lvert g(\{x\}) \rvert = 1$
- Substituting, $f(g(X) \cup \{y\}) - f(g(X)) \ge f(g(Y) \cup \{y\}) - f(g(Y))$
- The above is true because $f$ is submodular.

Is there a name for functions like $g$? Technically we don't need the full generality of $g(X \cup Y) = g(X) \cup g(Y)$; it would suffice to have $g(X \cup \{x\}) = g(X) \cup g(\{x\})$. Is that formulation equivalent? Are there well-known properties more specific than the above that imply the conditions above?

Comment: Q1 and Q3: There is not like to be a name for such functions because the condition. Q2: Use recursion to show equivalence (as you already observed, one direction is immediate).

Comment: @dohmatob: I don't understand what you mean regarding Q1 and Q3.

Answer (score 1):

$f(X \cup \{x\}) - f(X) \ge f(Y \cup \{x\}) - f(Y)$, where $X \subseteq Y$, is one way to characterize submodular functions, but not the only way. An equivalent formulation is $f(X) + f(Y) \ge f(X \cup Y) + f(X \cap Y)$. By applying similar reasoning to that expression, you can find that $f \circ g$ is submodular when $f$ is submodular and $g$ preserves finite intersections and unions (equivalently: $g$ is a monotone bijection with monotone inverse, $g$ is a lattice homomorphism).